# Symbolizing two variables of a shapefile in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have a shapefile with two variables: population and education level, I am trying to visualize both of the variables together. For example- the population can be represented by the circles with gradually increasing sizes and the education level by the gradual colors. What symbology can I use to do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use proportional symbols and Graduated symbols from Layer properties -Symbology.

Comment: I can select only one field with graduated symbols but I want to show two fields together. I tried  `multiple attributes` in symbology, it works but it repeats the color bands, I want either graduated or different colors for all parameters